# Java Project in VS-Code, "No delegateCommandHandler for vscode.java.validateLaunchConfig" Error

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I'm new to Java in Visual Studio Code and trying to implement small application, which is using our SDK, which is located in our internal Git Repository.

When trying to Debug my application I get following Error:

> No delegateCommandHandler for vscode.java.validateLaunchConfig

My Configurationfile looks pretty simple:

```
{
    "configurations": [

        {
            "type": "java",
            "name": "CodeLens (Launch) - App",
            "request": "launch",
            "mainClass": "com.my.first.class",
            "projectName": "dummyproject"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm using following Extensions for Visual Studio Code:

- Debugger for Java (0.20.0)
- Gitlens (9.9.0)
- Java Dependency Viewer (0.5.1)
- Java Test Runner (0.18.1)
- Maven for Java (0.18.1)
- Java Extension Pack (0.7.1)
- Language Support for Java (0.47.0)
- Visual Studio IntelliCode (1.1.8)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Restarting Visual Studio Code solved this issue...

Comment: Can't believe it just worked, microsoft should see this and fix the reason behind it.

Comment: "turn it off and on again" - it shouldn't work, but it does!

Comment: Got a similar issue on Emacs lsp-java. Would be better if the exact reason is known...

Comment: @Rich S and probably against all forum rules. Thank you for the ideal link to IT Crowd: "Have you tried turning it off and on again." :) But to anyone who does not know it yet, at best, do not start watching it.

Comment: Didn't work for me.

Comment: Did not work for me either.

Answer (score 1):

Switching to Release Version of the Java Debugger extension and then reloading VSCode solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, some of them (Test Runner for Java and Debugger for Java) had a "reload required" button next to the uninstall button. After I pressed them, the error you mentioned disappeared and it worked well. Maybe it helps.:)

Answer (score 0):

if nothing of the other solutions work for you, go to your Extensions and press the button "revert to pre-release" to all java extensions, reload VS Code and *voilá*

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to **Extensions** in VS Code
2. Then click on **Debugger for Java**
3. Then click on "**Switch to Release Version**" which is beside **disable and uninstall**